# Flutter in Opera

Tags: flutter, opera

How do I add opera, preferably opera GX, to the available browsers to run a flutter app on the web?

When I run the command 'flutter run -d opera' it doesn't access that 'device id', only chrome and edge.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4LM7.png)

Comment: Opera is, since long ago, just a Chrome clone, so if you test on Chrome, it'll work in the very same way in Opera.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Opera is not supported as a development target. As per the official documentation:

> Which web browsers are supported by Flutter? Flutter web apps can run
> on the following browsers:
>
> Chrome (mobile & desktop) Safari (mobile & desktop) Edge (mobile &
> desktop) Firefox (mobile & desktop)

> During development, Chrome (on
> macOS, Windows, and Linux) and Edge (on Windows) are supported as the
> default browsers for debugging your app.

Note that, your app will probably run fine on Opera, it's just not supported for debugging your code (as in `flutter run`)